# Kubuntu release upgrade error (14.04 to 15.10)

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.04, kubuntu, 15.10

I am currently running 14.04, LTS, and I would like to update to 15.10. So I go on muon and click distro upgrade, top bar, and go to do other things.
After a while it comes up with this error:

[image]

I looked around on the internet a bit but I could find no obvious reason for this error, I have basically nothing installed as I recently did a complete reinstall, outside of dwarf fortress, steam, and grub.
The distro it was upgrading it to was 15.04, from 14.04 LTS.

Edit: I was asked to put the output of `grep "^deb" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` which gives the output of `grep: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*: No such file or directory`

Comment: Do you have any software installed through PPAs, binary `.deb` packages, source packages using the `make` command or similar stuff except the official repositories? Add the output of `grep "^deb" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` (will list all used PPAs)  to your question by [edit]ing it, please.

Comment: i may be wrong on this, but I think (K)Ubuntu cannot skip a version during upgrade. So, it should try to upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10, then to 15.04, then to 15.10. The problem is, 14.10 has reached its end of life. So it may not be available in the standard repositories any more.

Comment: @ByteCommander as far as I am aware I have not installed anything  through the methods listed, only through muon or `sudo apt-get install package_name`.

Comment: @user68186  Do you know how I would force it to upgrade to 14.10 then?

Comment: Try booting from a LiveUSB/DVD of Kubuntu 15.10 and start the install process.  It should give you the option to upgrade the existing version to the new one. If that option is not present, abort installaion. In any case backup your data first. If this works I will write a full answer.